# Printing out most expensive boat and it's information from an array

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I am working on a boat program that has a super class (Boat) and two subclasses (SailBoat, Powerboat) and I must print out all of the boats information and price as well as the most expensive boat and it's information alone.  This is the part I am having trouble with since I am not entirely sure how to go about it.  Here is what I have so far...

Boat Class:

```
public class Boat {
    String color;
    int length;

    public Boat() {
        color = "white";
        length = 20;
    }

    public Boat(String col, int leng) {
        color = col;
        length = leng;
    }

    public boolean setColor(String col) {
        if ("white".equals(col) || "red".equals(col) || "blue".equals(col) || "yellow".equals(col)) {
            col = color;
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: can only be white, red, blue or yellow");
            return false;
        }

    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public boolean setLength(int leng) {

        if (leng < 20 || leng > 50) {
            leng = length;
            System.out.println("Sail Boats can only be between 20 and 50 feet, inclusively.");
            return false;

        } else {
            return true;

        }
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String string;
        string = String.format("Color = " + color + " Length = " + length);
        return string;
    }

    public int calcPrice() {
        int price;
        price = 5000 + length;
        return price;
    }
}
```

PowerBoat Subclass

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class PowerBoat extends Boat {
    int engineSize;

    public PowerBoat() {
        super();
        engineSize = 5;
    }

    public PowerBoat(String col, int len, int esize) {
        this.color = col;
        this.length = len;
        engineSize = esize;
    }

    public boolean setEngineSize(int esize) {
        if (esize < 5 || esize > 350) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Error: That engine is too powerful.  The engine size must be between 1 and 350, inclusively");
            esize = engineSize;
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }

    public int calcPrice() {
        int price;
        price = 5000 + length * 300 + engineSize * 20;
        return price;
    }

    public String toString() {
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        return super.toString() + " Engine Size = " + engineSize + " Price = " + nf.format(calcPrice());
    }
}
```

SailBoat subclass

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class SailBoat extends Boat {

    int numSails;

    public SailBoat() {
        numSails = 0;
    }

    public SailBoat(String col, int leng, int numsail) {
        color = col;
        length = leng;
        numSails = numsail;
    }

    public boolean setNumSails(int nsails) {
        if (nsails < 1 || nsails > 4) {
            nsails = numSails;
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } // end setNumSails

    public int getNumSails() {
        return numSails;
    }

    public int calcPrice() {
        int price;
        price = length * 1000 + numSails * 2000;
        return price;
    }

    public String toString() {
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        return super.toString() + "Color: " + color + " Length: " + length + " Number Sails = " + numSails + " Cost = "
                + nf.format(calcPrice());
    }

    public int getTotalCost() {
        int totalCost = 0;
        totalCost += calcPrice();
        return totalCost;
    }
}
```

Inventory class (tester)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Inventory {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // boat objects
        Boat pb1 = new PowerBoat("blue", 22, 60);
        Boat sb1 = new SailBoat("white", 20, 1);
        Boat sb2 = new SailBoat("red", 42, 3);
        Boat pb2 = new PowerBoat("yellow", 35, 80);
        Boat pb3 = new PowerBoat("red", 50, 120);
        Boat sb3 = new SailBoat("blue", 33, 2);
        Boat pb4 = new PowerBoat("white", 20, 10);

        ArrayList<Boat> AL = new ArrayList<Boat>();
        // add boat objects to arraylist
        AL.add(pb1);
        AL.add(sb1);
        AL.add(sb2);
        AL.add(pb2);
        AL.add(pb3);
        AL.add(sb3);
        AL.add(pb4);

        // print all boat objects
        System.out.println("Print all boats");
        for (Boat anyBoat : AL) {
            System.out.println(anyBoat.toString());
        }

        int max = 0;
        int totalcost = 0;
        Boat mostExpensiveBoat = null;
        for (Boat anyBoat : AL) {
            if (anyBoat instanceof SailBoat) {
                totalcost += anyBoat.calcPrice();
                if (anyBoat.calcPrice() > max) {
                    max = anyBoat.calcPrice();
                    mostExpensiveBoat = anyBoat;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am really confused on how to finish up this program, the results I am supposed to get after all the boat information is printed is this..

```
Total price of all boats is $ 170,500.00
Most Expensive Boat: Color = red  Length = 42  Number Sails = 3 Cost = $ 48,000.00
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the output you are currently getting?

Comment: Method `getTotalCost()` on `SailBoat` makes no sense, and since you're not using it, remove it. --- Your "most expensive" loop only looks at sailboats. Why? Remove the `if` statement so *all* boat are examined. --- You won't get desired output unless you add some `print()` statements.

Comment: I'm confused. Firstly, your question is how to print the information of the most expensive boat, but when you initialize the `max` variable, you only do it if the boat is an instance of `SailBoat`. If you only wish to find the most expensive `SailBoat`, then this is correct. Otherwise, you should remove `if (anyBoat instanceof SailBoat)`. Secondly, I'm not sure why you're stuck with printing the information. You already have `max` initialized as well as `mostExpensiveBoat`. Simply call System.out.println() to print the desired values after the final for loop.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few design flaws you should correct:

1. Your `Boat` class should be an `interface` or `abstract`. You can't have a boat that isn't a power boat or sail boat so you should not be able to instantiate one.
2. Your instance variables should be `private`.
3. Make methods abstract that need to be defined by subclasses of `Boat` (e.g. `calcPrice`).

If you are able to use Java 8 then there's a nice way of getting the most expensive boat. The following code will print the most expensive boat (using `Boat.toString`) if one is present.

```
allBoats.stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Boat::calcPrince))
    .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

That avoids having to write the code that manually iterates through your list comparing prices. It also copes with the situation of an empty list (which means there is no maximum). Otherwise you need to initialise to `null` and compare to `null` before printing.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop should look like this:

```
for (Boat anyBoat : AL) {
    totalcost += anyBoat.calcPrice();
    if (anyBoat.calcPrice() > max) {
        max = anyBoat.calcPrice();
        mostExpensiveBoat = anyBoat;
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter if it's a sailBoat or not, you just wanna print the information of the most expensive one, so you can remove the instanceof condition. After that:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

System.out.println("Total price of all boats is " +   nf.format(totalcost));
System.out.println("Most expensive boat: " + mostExpensiveBoat.toString());
```

Should work, since you have already overriden the toString() methods.

one more thing: In your SailBoat toString() method, you are doing:

```
return super.toString() + "Color: " + color + " Length: " + length + " Number Sails = " + numSails + " Cost = "
            + nf.format(calcPrice());
```

When you call the super.toString() you are printing the color and the length twice; just call

```
return super.toString() + " Number Sails = " + numSails + " Cost = " + nf.format(calcPrice());
```